# Ubuntu background changer not showing new images in /usr/share/backgrounds

Tags: 14.04, directory, desktop-background, default, appearance

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I wanted to add some more wallpapers to it. So I copied some wallpapers to /usr/share/backgrounds. But the wallpaper changer (All settings --> Appearance --> Look) does not show the new images that I copied. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/trusty-wallpapers.xml`,  which is a real pain, especially with lots of long file names.

It's easier to leave the pictures in the Pictures folder and direct Appearance to that with the drop down menu (set on Wallpapers by default).

I don't know if you can create a sub folder in Pictures that Appearance can access.

Answer (score 0):

I think. A cause It's due to Permissions. Strangely, sometimes the Wallpapers are saved without permissions to `group` and `others` on User profile folder or Partition Data.
Supposedly, the wallpapers need "Read permissions" to they, it being /usr/share/backgrounds/ a Root folder.

From Terminal inside --> `/usr/share/backgrounds/<My-personal-wallpapers-using>`, become as root I use the command:

`sudo chmod 0644 *` « or » `sudo chmod go+r *`

Or maybe, fix the permissions from Origin folder before to copying.

Then, so those NEW wallpapers pasted to destiny, now they are displayed from the GUI Changer Wallpapers.

For all wallpaper images the permissions must be displayed as: `-rw-r--r--`